# Reading JSON data into an array/list with Jackson

Tags: java, arrays, json, jackson

I have seen and read several questions on this subject, but none seem to address my problem.  In all likelihood, I am making one (or two) minor but critical mistakes, but I don't see them.

My JSON looks like this (the real example is much more complex but this is what I have whittled it down to):

```
[
  {
    "atcID": "AL011851"
  },
  {
   "atcID": "AL021851"
  }
]
```

The code I used to read it is:

StormData.java:

```
public class StormData {

@JsonCreator
StormData ( String atcID, String name ) {
    this.atcID = atcID;
    this.name = name;
};

public String getAtcID()    {
    return atcID;
}

public void setAtcID( String atcID )    {
    this.atcID = atcID;
}

String      atcID;
String      name;

}
```

Main file:

```
byte[] jsonData = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(fileName));

ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

List<StormData> myObjects = objectMapper.readValue(jsonData , new TypeReference<List<StormData>>(){});
```

But the error I get is:

```
Cannot construct instance of `StormData` (although at least one Creator exists): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
```

So what am I missing?  TIA.

Comment: Try to create default constructor. If you want to use one-argument constructor use `@JsonCreator` annotation. In your example Jackson tries to create object and after that use setter methods to set properties.

Comment: OK, if I add @JsonCreator to the constructor (see edit above in original (edited) post), then it works!  But if I then add a second field, 'name', (see edit above), then I get a new error:       Invalid type definition for type `StormData`: Argument #0 has no property name, is not Injectable: can not use as Creator [constructor for StormData, annotations:

Comment: Try to use @JsonProperty. Example: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/#annotations-using-custom-constructor

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  But first, JsonProperty generates an error "not allowed in this position".  If I ignore that, then I am back to "Cannot construct instance of `StormData` (no Creators..."

Comment: You need to use both annotations: `@JsonCreator` on constructor and `@JsonProperty` on each argument. See the link to the official documentation I gave you above. Works for me.

Comment: Ah, that worked.  Many thanks!  Should have read more carefully.  Still, so much easier in JavaScript (no annotations, etc.) but that is the difference between JavaScript and a strongly typed language like Java. I'd give it a green check, but you can't do that for a comment.

Comment: Still, it seems rather convoluted.  I did a project a while ago using Java reflection and was able to dynamically load all sorts of objects without requiring little "annotations" to tell me what was what.  Not sure why it is necessary in this context.

Comment: I think that [javadoc](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonCreator.html) can answer your question: `Also note that all JsonProperty annotations must specify actual name (NOT empty String for "default") unless you use one of extension modules that can detect parameter name; this because default JDK versions before 8 have not been able to store and/or retrieve parameter names from bytecode. But with JDK 8 (or using helper libraries such as Paranamer, or other JVM languages like Scala or Kotlin), specifying name is optional. `

Comment: I've updated the answer with the information how to rid of `@JsonProperty` annotations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use both annotations: `@JsonCreator` on constructor and `@JsonProperty` on each argument:

```
@JsonCreator
StormData (@JsonProperty("atcID") String atcID, @JsonProperty("name") String name) {
    this.atcID = atcID;
    this.name = name;
}
```

See [the official documentation](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/#annotations-using-custom-constructor).

Since JDK 8 you can also register Jackson `ParameterNamesModule` and compile your code with `-parameters` option.
See the details in [the documentation](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8/tree/master/parameter-names).